# Is this duplicate instance of ContentValues redundant?

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

In [this NotePadProvider sample code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.4_r1/com/example/android/notepad/NotePadProvider.java#NotePadProvider.insert%28android.net.Uri,android.content.ContentValues%29), I noticed that the `ContentValues` parameter is duplicated even if it's not null:

```
ContentValues values;
if (initialValues != null) {
    values = new ContentValues(initialValues);
} else {
    values = new ContentValues();
}
```

On the face of it, this looks redundant. It looks like it would be more efficient to just write:

```
ContentValues values;
if (initialValues != null) {
    values = initialValues;
} else {
    values = new ContentValues();
}
```

But that's not what the author of the sample chose to do and my question is **Why?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not equivalent. The original code creates a copy of 'initialValues', the method then proceeds to modify the new instance in the variable `value`. This way the `ContentValues` instance supplied to that `insert` method is **not** modified by this method.

Your version does modify the original object, which might have unwanted side-effects in other areas of the program.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the side effect possibility. It slipped my attention.